# Access-Control-Allow-Origin not working with Apache2, Mirador and Loris

Tags: apache, .htaccess, google-chrome, cors

I'm trying to set up a Loris server to serve some images of medieval architecture and texts that I have, with a Mirador viewer set up to view the images. Loris is running on an Ubuntu 16.04 LTS box and Mirador is on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. This setup works great when everything runs on the same server, but I'm running into a CORS issue if I try to access the manifests from a different location.

Adding a manifest to Mirador from the Loris server works fine -- the manifest appears with the thumbnail -- but clicking on that thumbnail results in a black canvas. Checking the error console, the error being reported is `"XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://208.113.167.107/loris/01/04/124A2505.tif/info.json. Origin http://www.minorworksoflydgate.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."`

Checking it in Chrome comes back with `"XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://208.113.165.33/loris/Lydgate/Testament/Clopton/sw_test_3.jpg/info.json. The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed. Origin 'http://www.minorworksoflydgate.net' is therefore not allowed access."`

Since the issue seems to be the image, rather than the manifest, I'm wondering if the issue is that the image folder doesn't have the proper permissions to allow CORS requests. Chrome is showing that two header requests are being passed, but removing the header request from `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` means results in an error that no headers are being sent at all.

Is there a location I need to be aware of or make sure everything is placed in, or some configuration line I need to uncomment or add in order to make it work? Everything I've read suggests it should be working at this point so I'm lost.

Comment: Chrome gives this error: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://208.113.167.107/loris/01/04/124A2505.tif/info.json. The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed. Origin 'http://www.minorworksoflydgate.net' is therefore not allowed access.

I need to figure out where the duplicate header call is, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out enough to solve my problem. `set_acao` in webapp.py, when defined, added the extra header statement. Why it did not trigger unless I added a header to `000-default.conf`, I don't know, but commenting it out solved my immediate problem so I'm good.